# Implementing classes that should behave as Optional

Tags: java, oop, option-type

Imagine finding out if two shapes intersect. An intersection of two shapes may be either another shape, or nothing. If there is no `intersects(Shape)` method in `Shape`, then, I believe, the proper object-oriented solution would be:

```
public final class ShapesIntersection implements Maybe<Shape> {
    public ShapesIntersection(Shape a, Shape b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPresent() {
        // find out if shapes intersect
    }

    @Override
    public Shape get() {
        // find the common piece of two shapes
    }
}
```

In JDK, `Optional` is a `final` class, not an interface. To properly solve problems like this one, I'm going to write my own `Maybe` interface that will look like this:

```
public inteface Maybe<T> {
    T get();
    boolean isPresent();
    default Optional<T> asOptional() {
       return isPresent() ?
           Optional.of(get()) :
           Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

What caveats may there be if I stick to this solution implementing Maybe whenever I need optional behavior? Also, this task seems to be quite universal. Am I reinventing the wheel here with introducing my own `Maybe` interface?

I should add that the whole hassle with a separate class and interface is to omit implementing the behavior using static methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As rolfl said, this is a strange idea. Imagine you want to compute *x*<sup>*y*</sup> for two `int`s. Sometimes it's undefined, so would you implement a `Maybe<Integer>`? And then another implementation for e.g. nCr(*x*, *y*)?

This sound wrong, doesn't it? The problem is that you're binding the origin of the thing (intersection, power, choose) to the thing itself. But an intersection of two `Shape`s is nothing but a `Shape` again (or nothing at all, which can be nicely represented via `Optional`. *Or even better with `null`; just call me old-school).*

The OO aproach makes no sense here, as there's no new kind of object. 2<sup>2</sup> is exactly the same thing as nCr(4, 1) and both are exactly of the same kind as 4.

Another thing is that you have to call the `ShapesIntersection` constructor. This is actually a *static* call, so you may as well write a static helper method instead.

Extending `Shape` by some `IntersectableShape` might make sense. There are cases when some operations are common enough for such a thing, see e.g. [FluentIterable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html), but I doubt you'd make that many intersections.

Answer (score 8):

You are reinventing the wheel here. The reason Optional is final, is because there is really no reason to change it, and the internal semantics require consistency across the usage.

The real issue here is the logic of your constructor. You should not be using a constructor to determine the logic of the intersection. What you want is a (static?) method that performs the calculation for you, and returns the relevant Optional.

```
public static Optional<Shape> intersection(Shape a, Shape b) {
    // compute if there is an overlap
    if (!checkOverlaps(a,b)) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    Shape intersection  = ....
    return Optional.of(intersection);
}
```

Note that the [`Optional.empty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--) and [`Optional.of(....)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of-T-) are factory methods that create appropriate instances of the Optional. Java 8 streams, functions, and other supporting structures use a number of static factory methods to create instances of these otherwise final classes.

Comment: Then whose method could `intersection(Shape, Shape)` be? Whose behavior is it to determine an intersection of two shapes? A `ShapeIntersector`? If it is `ShapeIntersector`, then I believe this is a bad design (for example, [this article](http://objology.blogspot.ru/2011/09/one-of-best-bits-of-programming-advice.html)) explains my views. I think an intersection should compute itself. Maybe you could provide a third option?

Comment: Ah, I see you redeclared the method to be static. I think static methods are completely against the OO paradigm, hence my solution suggested in the post.

Comment: @Suseika - you may feel justified in your dislike for static methods. On the other hand, it is the 'right' way to solve your problem using Java native methods. An alternative option would be to make a new shape interface with a default `intersection` method that takes the 'other' shape as an argument, but that would be harder than a static utility method. Your dislike for static methods does not impact my feeling about my answer... my answer is how I would suggest you solve it using standard Java practice.